# reading xml file inside a jar-package

Tags: java, xml, file, jar, package

Here's my structure:

- com/mycompany/ValueReader.class
- com/mycompany/resources/values.xml

I can read the file in my Eclipse project, but when I export it to a .jar it can never find the values.xml.

I tried using ValueReader.class.getResource() and ValueReader.class.getResourceAsStream() but it doesn't work.

What's the problem here?
How do I get a File-object to my values.xml?

B.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504272/shipping-java-code-with-data-baked-into-the-jar

Answer (score 8):

You can't get a `File` object (since it's no longer a file once it's in the .jar), but you should be able to get it as a stream via `getResourceAsStream(path);`, where `path` is the *complete* path to your class.

e.g.

```
/com/mycompany/resources/values.xml
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work.

Your approach was correct tho.

I used getResourceAsStream(path), but instead of path=com/mycompany/resources/values.xml, i used path=resources/values.xml and it's working.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: it hasn't worked because you didn't put the leading slash, which means the root of the classpath. Without it the path is relative.

Comment: Ah true.

Thanks.  I'll never forget this anymore!

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a `File` for the file because it's in a jar file. But you can get an input stream:

```
InputStream in = ValueReader.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/values.xml");
```

`getResourceAsStream` and `getResource` convert the package of the class to a file path, then add on the argument. This will give a stream for the file at path `/com/mycompany/resources/values.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work...

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("com/mycompany/resources/values.xml")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extract the jar then take what you want, in the same class-path using :

```
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new   
FileInputStream(zipfile.getCanonicalFile())));
```