# Resources with Eclipse and runnable Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar, file-import

I've the following file structure:

```
+-src
  +-- code
+-resources
  +-- img
    +- logo.png
  +-- defaultConfig
    +- config.xml
```

When i run the code in Eclipse it worked, since exporting to runnable jar, it haven't found the `defaultConfig` files

I'm Accessing a Logo this way and it works

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/img/logo.png");
setIconImage(new ImageIcon(url).getImage());
```

Accessing the `config.xml` doesn't work with different set ups.

this was given:

```
File config = new File("resources/defaultConfig/config.xml");
```

after a lot of searching i tried this one:

```
//example
String path = "resources\\defaultConfig\\config.xml");
File config = new File(createURIFromString(path));
```

I've tried it with `./` & `.\` without `.`

```
private URI createURIFromString(String path) {
    URI id = null;
    try {
        id =    getClass().getResource(path).toURI();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return id;
}
```

Result is a `null` Pointer.

I've tried

- to add the folder to the resource dir
- to add the folder to the root dir (same layer like src)
- add the Config folder to the resource dir

**Solution:**

previously the file weren't in the jar, so till using the `getResorce` method, it works.

Comment: how can i read the files

Comment: Are you sure everything is packed in the jar?

Comment: i've opend the jar with zip, everything is packed in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you creating a `File` object? Your data is embedded within the jar file; there's no `File` object you can construct that refers to it (unless you've got a custom file system somewhere).

You need to rip out anything which *requires* the configuration to be read from a file, and instead make it take any `InputStream`. You can then use

```
InputStream stream = Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("/defaultConfig/config.xml");
```

Comment: @MemLeak: Then you'll need to change that, or extract your resource to disk before you read it.

Comment: @DaSh: Well that isn't even valid code, and we don't really have enough information to help you. I suggest you ask a new question - see http://tinyurl.com/so-list for more information about what will make a good question.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you
[reading xml file inside a jar-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552793/reading-xml-file-inside-a-jar-package)

"You can't get a File object (since it's no longer a file once it's in the .jar), but you should be able to get it as a stream via getResourceAsStream(path)"

Answer (score 0):

If everything is packed, then you should get resources with the `getResource` the same way you get the images but may be different path.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/defaultConfig/config.xml");
```

Then you can read directly from this url. See [Reading Directly from a URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html).

> ```java
> BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
>
> String inputLine;
> while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
>     System.out.println(inputLine);
> in.close();
> ```