# Struts2 store file

Tags: file, struts2, store

I am working on my first struts2 project, using tomcat7 and eclipse. I need to put txt file on server and read data from it. I try to put file in sourse project directory and use standard java read from file

```java
try {
   File file = new File("hello.txt");
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
   while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
   }
   scanner.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

but it isn't work. Where to put text file(it must not refresh after restart program/tomcat, if it's possible), and how to read/write to it? 
Help please, is it a good files tutorial?

Comment: You need to put the file on the class path and read it as a resource.

Comment: it's work! InputStream istr = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.txt"); String text = IOUtils.toString(istr, "UTF-8"); file.txt is in src

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resources with Eclipse and runnable Jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073497/resources-with-eclipse-and-runnable-jar)

Comment: but how to add to project file and WRITE in it later?

Answer (score 0):

You can use fileUtils.copyfile(file1,file2) its from commons-io  jar

first of get the file's Absolute path and then copy file on those server path

then you can modify ,read, and write file