# Java WebApp: Loading resource from .jar located in WEB-INF

Tags: java, jar, resources, web-inf

There are a lot of similar questions, but, probably, mine is a little bit different:

What is the right way to load resource from inside of `.jar` file located in `WEB-INF/lib` folder (if I know the jar file name and the name of the class it resource belongs to), while Web Application is running? Should I use `getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(?)` for this purpose or the `<name-of-known-class>.getResourseAsStream(?)`, and what path do I need to specify there?

So, the structure is:

```
/WEB-INF
    /classes
        /some/package/name
           ?.class #some Java code or Servlet that tries to read 'required-file.xml'
    /lib
        /<jar-with-known-name>.jar
            /another/package/with/known/name
                SomeKnownClass.class
                required-file.xml
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552793/reading-xml-file-inside-a-jar-package
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504272/shipping-java-code-with-data-baked-into-the-jar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/howto-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive

Questions that seem similar

My difference: I usually specify `getServletContext.getResourceAsStream('/WEB-INF/classes/blah/blah/resource.xml')` to load resources that are not in `.jar`s. If it is not wrong,what path is for jarred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `<name-of-known-class>.getResourseAsStream(?)`, which loads resources using the "local" classloader. In the case of a webapp, this will use the webapp's classloader.

The `getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(?)` method will return webapp resources relative to the webapp root, and cannot look inside JAR files.

The [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) for this method describes the path you need to specify, but essentially you can use paths relative to the known class, e.g.

```
SomeKnownClass.class.getResourceAsStream("required-file.xml");
```